# perl regular expression to separate each letter in the text

Tags: regex, perl

How do you use perl regular expression to convert the following text:

```
1100101
1100111
1110001
1110101
```

into

```
1 1 0 0 1 0 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

I tried using

```
perl -pe 's// /g' < text.txt
```

but it gave me some funny results like this:

```
 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
  1 1 0 0 1 1 1
  1 1 1 0 0 0 1
  1 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=[^\n])([^\n])/ \1/g'
```

Answer (score 5):

Why use regular expressions at all?

```
perl -pe '$_ = join " ", split ""'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using look-ahead:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d)(?=.)/$1 /g'
```

Using look-ahead and look-behind:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=\d)(?=.)/ /g'
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way using auto-split:

```
 perl -F// -ane 'print "@F";' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Or like this ...

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<!^)(\d)/ \1/g' input
1 1 0 0 1 0 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

... there is a nice explanation of negative regex here: 
[negative regex for perl string pattern match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361312/negative-regex-for-perl-string-pattern-match)

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there:

```
perl -pe 's/(.)/$1 /g' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
1100101
1100111
1110001
1110101
> perl -pe 's/(.)/$1 /g' temp
1 1 0 0 1 0 1 
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 
1 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: This adds a space to the end of each line.