# Negative matching regexp is not working in perl?

Tags: perl

[negative regex for perl string pattern match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361312/negative-regex-for-perl-string-pattern-match) 
I seen this question and answer but which answers are not suited for my problem. But my question also like this, My script below

```
 use warnings;
 use strict;
 my @data = <DATA>;
 my @match = grep{m/^SEQ.+(!?ALA)/g} @data;
 print "@match\n";
 __DATA__
 SEQ HMK 112 ALA 123 
 SEQ ALA 322
 SEQ 121 ALA 333
 SEQ 114 PHE 443
 SEQ 11433 GLY 332
 SEQ 1123 VAL 121
 SEQ 1121 ALA 321
 SEQ 981 TRP 44532
 SEQ 887 TRP 90
 SEQ 11 HIS SPR 443
 HTTM SHH 121
 HTTM MME 221
 HTTM VZE 9
 EXP 112
 EXP 334 SMZ
```

I expect, First check the beginning of the word ***SEQ*** But not match ***ALA*** line.
I expect output is:

```
SEQ 114 PHE 443
SEQ 11433 GLY 332
SEQ 1123 VAL 121
SEQ 981 TRP 44532
SEQ 887 TRP 90
SEQ 11 HIS SPR 443
```

How can i do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're really close, the regex should be:

```
my @match = grep{m/^SEQ(?!.+ALA)/} @data;
```

Just put the pattern `.+` inside the negative lookahead.
If it's outside, every lines match because you"re searching for a line that begins with `SEQ`  followed by any number of any character (ie. `SEQ HMK 112 ALA 123` matches) then something that is not `ALA`, -> OK because there is not `ALA` after the whole line.

Comment: Whilst you're spot on, I'm personally very wary of the dangers of regular expressions - they have a nasty habit of growing big and scary and one day will ambush you.

Comment: @Sobrique:It may be true in some cases, but, here, the regex is realy simple.

Answer (score 4):

```
while ( <DATA> ) {
    next if m/ALA/;
    print if m/^SEQ/;
}
```

I'm sure someone can give you a regex-based answer, but this IMO is clearer what's going on.

I think you've two problems with negative matching. One is that `.+` is greedy - so your 'ALA' is matching that, and the 'negative match' is true. 
The other is - you've got the `?!` the wrong way around.

Comment: In the OP's form in case he's not actually printing: `my @match = grep { /ALA/ && !/SEQ/ } @data;`

Comment: Fair point - i'd probably stick with a loop and a `push ( @matches, $_ );` type approach, but at that point it's more because I generally prefer it to a complicated `grep`.